# Não consigo retornar o usuário autenticado no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Bom dia
No meu projeto, faço a autenticação padrão fornecida pelo Laravel 5, daí ele direciona para o meu home normalmente quando loga. Sei que logou normalmente porque quando coloco dados errados ele retorna erro. Nessa hora eu tento pegar o usuário logado `$user = Auth::user();` e quando testo para ver se retornou o valor que eu quero ele diz que não construiu o objeto: "Trying to get property of non-object".

Até hoje nunca tinha trabalhado com autenticação no Laravel.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Abaixo os códigos
routes.php:

```
// Authentication routes...
Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');

Route::get('/', 'PrincipalController@home');
Route::get('home', 'PrincipalController@home');
```

Não mexi no AuthController, a não ser no `redirectTo`, que coloquei para o meu home. O login e o register fiz quase que exatamente como na documentação, só mudei o estilo. Não mexi no Model User, deixei exatamente como o padrão

PrincipalController.php:

```
use Auth;
use Redirect;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PrincipalController extends Controller{
    public function home(){
        //Pode fazer um array de atributos/objetos e mandar pelo compact (pode separar os parâmetros no compact por vírgula)
        $user = Auth::user();

        if($user){
            return view('home', compact('user'));
        }else{
            return view('auth/login');
        }
    }
}
```

AuthController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/';
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é a classe (model) que você definiu para ser a entidade de autenticação?

Comment: Não mudei a classe, estou usando tudo do padrão do Laravel, ou seja, o User mesmo

Comment: Verifique isso então:  `var_dump(Auth::user() instanceof User);`. Me fale o que retorna.

Comment: Retorna 'boolean false'

Comment: Vamos lá, segundo teste : `var_dump(Auth::check())`. Isso tem que retornar   `true` se estiver autenticado.

Comment: Retornou falso, mas é estranho porque ele só redireciona para o home se eu coloco os dados corretos de login

Comment: Hum... Já sei. Verifique no arquivo `session.php` que está dentro de config. Verifique se a configuração está como "array". Se estiver, mude para "file".

Comment: Nada, já estava como 'file', e olha que eu testei todas as configurações possíveis ('file', 'cookie', 'database', 'apc', 'memcached', 'redis', 'array')

Answer (score 3):

Descobri o que está acontecendo!

Estou seguindo a documentação do site, que pelo que constatei está na versão 5.0 e o meu Laravel está na versão 5.2.12, pois tinha atualizado recentemente.

O método para se fazer a autenticação padrão do Laravel é simplesmente executar o comanto `php artisan make:auth`, dessa forma ele cria os arquivos de login, register, email, reset, password, app e home, já deixa uma página bem desenhada pronta para editarmos, e o melhor, já utiliza o que eu tinha buscado.

Obrigado a quem veio me ajudando nos comentários da postagem

Comment: Eita... voltou no 5.0 ? Veja a página `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php` e veja a função que te falei agora...

Comment: Então, pelo que vi a função só tem mesmo a chamada para a função login, que aí sim tem o código que você mostrou, com algumas pequenas diferenças

Comment: Era dessa mesmo que estava falando `postLogin` e não `getLogin()`.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei o que aconteceu com seu Laravel, ou se é assim mesmo, mas a função `postLogin()` que tem nesse arquivo `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php` devem estar assim:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
        {
            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        }

        return redirect($this->loginPath())
                    ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
                    ->withErrors([
                        'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
                    ]);
    }
```

Tenta substituir pela que tá aí e veja no que dá.

O arquivo `session.php` tem que estar `file`.